# Как вызвать функцию в компоненте после того как свойство в vuex store изменится?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

У меня есть хранилище данных в vuex и два компонент.
Первый компонент это range slider, в котором я меняю значения слайдера и сразу же отправляю их в store.
Второй это компонент в котором мне нужно вызвать мою функцию при изменении store.

*my store*

```
state: {
    value: 0,
      rgbColors: {
        red: 0
      }
  },
```

Как я понимаю мне нужно использовать store.subscribe.watch.rgbColors.red или store.watch.rgbColors.red ведь так?

И если это так то как это использовать и вызвать функцию при изменении значения?

Answer (score 0):

Просто поставьте `watcher` в нужном компоненте, не забыв замапить туда нужный state.

```
computed: {
    rgbColors() {
      return store.state.rgbColors;
    }
}

watch: {
    rgbColors: {
        handler(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue !== oldValue) {
                //ваш код
            }
        },
        deep: true //если нужно отслеживать изменение свойств
    }
}
```